# Change column values in pandas df under different conditions / invert answers on 4-point likert-scale

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a df I have some columns with answers on a 4-point Likert scale which I need to invert meaning I need to flip the values in each row of this column: 4->1, 2->3, 3->2, 4->1

I've tried this:

```
questDay1Df.loc[questDay1Df['STAI_State_01'] == 4] = 1
questDay1Df.loc[questDay1Df['STAI_State_01'] == 3] = 2
questDay1Df.loc[questDay1Df['STAI_State_01'] == 2] = 3
questDay1Df.loc[questDay1Df['STAI_State_01'] == 1] = 4
```

The problem is that since it's not in the same command, the lines are of course ran seperately. If for example 3 was changed to 2 in the next line it will be changed to 3 again. Any ideas how to prevent this problem/ how to write a command which does all of these conditional changes at once?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), but I think this solution is more fun :)

```
questDay1Df['STAI_State_01'] = np.abs(questDay1Df['STAI_State_01'] - 5)
```

The `.replace()` possibility is more widely applicable:

```
questDay1Df['STAI_State_01'] = questDay1Df['STAI_State_01'].replace({
    1: 4, 
    2: 3, 
    3: 2, 
    4: 1,
})
```

Comment: yes, the abs is indeed a very good idea and makes it a lot shorter. Thank you very much!